# remove "-" (soft hyphen) between words

Tags: replace, query-replace

When I try to paste a text from a web page inside Emacs I get this "-" between words. Here is one example:

[image]

Is there a way to get rid of this (don't know the term..) ?

> Aus Sicht vie­ler Deut­scher ist Russ­land ein rät­sel­haf­tes Land. Ich habe elf Jah­re lang von dort für den SPIEGEL be­rich­tet, bis Ende 2009. Bis heu­te ver­fol­ge ich die Ent­wick­lung in dem Land, das ich je­des Jahr be­su­che.

Comment: This is most likely a soft hyphen inserted for browsers to hyphenate the text correctly. Put point on it and use `M-x describe-char` to verify that.

Comment: What @wasamasa said. Apply that info to the answer provided about replacing. (But you might also want to find out if there's a way to prevent this happening in the first place.)

Answer (score 2):

```lisp
(query-replace-regexp (format "\\b%c\\b" 173) "" )
```

or in interactive mode

`C-M-% \bC-x 8 RET ad RET \b RET RET`

the sequence `C-x 8 RET ad RET' is for generate the SOFT HYPHEN char (#xad =#173).

Comment: @gigair, unfortunately this doesn't seem to work

Comment: Yes, because the dash in the answer isn't the same as the dash in your text. Copy-paste it from the text into the replacement part of either part of the answer.

Comment: @Enrico Pirani. Posting text as an image isn't really a good idea. You should have provided the message text as text.

Comment: @gigiair if I post the text (copy paste from Emacs) the soft hyphen will disappear. The same happens when I paste in other program like TextEdit or Pages ... anyway this the text.

Comment: You can post verbatim using a pastebin. ix is an Emacs extension to do so. This is an example : http://ix.io/2K4F